# Authentication failure, when try to config G-Suite-send to GMail-read-IMAP

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have an old GMail (suppose `oldGmail@gmail.com`) and need to preserve it. When I need to add other mailbox (from another email-services provider), I use [standard GMail procedure for it](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) ("Send emails from a different address or alias" and supposing by **IMAP or POP3**), and was working fine...

Now I need to add, at the the same `oldGmail@gmail.com` mailbox,  suppose `newSuite@myDomin.com`...

The "other provider" now, of `newSuite@myDomin.com`,  is also Google, it is a  G-Suite mailbox.

So...  doing the something, the standard procedure, with `smtp.Gmail.com`, etc.  is not working, see errors:

```
... Check user/password newSuite@myDomin.com.
The server returned an error: "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtE 534-5.7.14 SsAeOI3HLcegpm38wB499UZcTOV-rxm3DBuc8TN2WBvWhNBRT3QWs7-7pNd1wDLPSH-lca 534-5.7.14 XPCHH68Rq2h9v8PO7zHe4UyLKDe3N1xKrJkDOQm8KPWYVK-pLfjpBbB238FpNOhV4vq8eo 534-5.7.14 hXoeZOodqQDTig_s9dN-P46mwhamqS4-rMlYB6qMQnsu0mYyNsIi3iaq-1Ilc-hvYikYXI 534-5.7.14 mA2XEIoBlGgAzh9h9SP2UP9-MG2d4> 
Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d8sm3825757uaa.5 - gsmtp code(534)
```

---

### Summarizing

I need that `newSuite@myDomin.com` mailbox sends information (by IMAP or POP no matter) to `oldGmail@gmail.com` mailbox... And that, at my oldGmail account, I can also send emails using the new as alias.

---

... Other possible problems:

- The form need  SMTP of `newSuite@myDomin.com` that I suppose `smtp.Gmail.com`, port ??
- not make sense, but... Need "gmailify"?

---

### Note after @Aug

After suggestion to two-factor in both accounts...

Using port 587 and SSL the error is:

```
Falha na autenticação. Verifique seu nome de usuário/senha e o acesso à opção Aplicativos menos seguros para newSuite@myDomin.com.
O servidor retornou um erro: "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a39sm1593325uai.52 - gsmtp code(535) "
```

Using port 465

```
Falha na autenticação. Verifique seu nome de usuário/senha e o acesso à opção Aplicativos menos seguros para newSuite@myDomin.com.
O servidor retornou um erro: "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e4sm6439653vke.35 - gsmtp code(535) "
```

Using TLS the waiting-time is bigger but...

- With port 465: "Não foi possível acessar o servidor. Verifique novamente o servidor e o número da porta."
- With port 587: same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Google generally disables IMAP by default due to security.

**For all Gmail accounts**

IMAP is disabled by default from within Gmail. [Enable](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) IMAP from with Gmail's settings. If you need help with **ports**, that link clarifies which ports to set.

**For 2FA enabled accounts**

Your Google username + password will not authenticate to IMAP. You need to generate an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) unique to that mail application (Thunderbird, masOS Mail, iOS Mail). Then use your username (aug@gmail.com) and App Password that was generated.

**For non-2FA accounts** (just password)

IMAP is disabled by default from within Google. Go to [their help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on the subject, and enable Less Secure Apps. Then log in using your Google username (aug@gmail.com) and regular Google password.

Comment: Hi @Aug, thanks (!). The "[help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)" is about "Allowing (...) to access your account", but my problem (the showed bug) is when my account is accessing other one, so, the inverse.

Comment: I suggest going into the Google settings for newSuite@mydomain.com and making sure you "Allow less secure apps." Maybe I'm not understanding your question. Are you trying to forward mail, or merge the two emails?

Comment: Thanks @Aug, do you have a link to this "Allow less secure apps" at GMail acoount of `newSuite@myDomin.com`?

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be more clear. Just comment any questions!